# Shopify function for showing percentages of sale doesn't work

Tags: shopify

I have a function which should show how many percents the price is off but instead is showing `-0 %`.

What I have so far is this

```
{% if settings.use_saleoff and variant_tmp.compare_at_price > variant_tmp.price %}
    <span>{{'products.product.sale' | t}}</span>
    <span class="price_percentage">-{{ variant_tmp.compare_at_price | minus: variant_tmp.price | times: 100.0 | divided_by: variant_tmp.compare_at_price | money_without_currency | times: 100 | remove: '.0'}}%</span>
{% endif %}
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the right way:

```
{% if settings.use_saleoff and variant_tmp.compare_at_price > variant_tmp.price %}
    <span>{{'products.product.sale' | t}}</span>
    <span class="price_percentage">{{ 1.00 | times: variant_tmp.price | divided_by: variant_tmp.compare_at_price | times: 100 | round | minus: 100 }}%</span>
{% endif %}
```

At the first point, you have to show that the number will have decimal point.

Also, you have `money_without_currency` which will add something like this `$100 USD` and the letters will break the math logic after that.